# Move some items to the end of the array if they fulfill a specific condition

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array of paths that I would like to sort ...

```
Array
(
    /something/foo1
    /something/special/foo2
    /something/foo3
    /something/special/foo4
    /something/foo5
    /something/special/foo6
)
```

... so that all paths that contain `/special/` end up at the end of the array like this:

```
Array
(
    /something/foo1
    /something/foo3
    /something/foo5
    /something/special/foo2
    /something/special/foo4
    /something/special/foo6
)
```

The original sort order of paths must remain the same (so `1,2,3,4,5,6` => `1,3,5,2,4,6`). Is there an elegant way to do this? Can this be implemented by using the usort function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `unset` and append `[]`, like so

```
$x = array(1,2,3);
$x[] = $x[1];
unset($x[1]);
print_r($x);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
)
```

You can thus loop over the array, test each element, and flip to the end the ones that contain the pattern.

```
$len = count($a);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    if (...) {
        $a[] = $a[i];
        unset($a[i]);
    }
}
```

Edit: php's arrays are lists, hashes and arrays simultaneously.  It is possible to move an element to the end while retaining its index!  For example

```
$a = array(1,2,3);

$t = $a[1];
unset($a[1]);
$a[1] = $t;

print_r($a);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
    [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: This does not maintain the index association as requested

Comment: it wasn't the index association that had to be maintained, but the sort order.  The association too can be maintained by explicitly assigning the subscript; `$t = $a[$i]; unset($a[$i]); $a[$i] = $t;` will move $t to the end with the same index that it had before.  Php has really funky arrays.

Comment: He did specify the order using the same keys. Regardless, this doesn't appear to actually do what he requested... where is the sorting?

Comment: those were not keys, those were stand-ins for the rows. 1 == .../foo1, 2 == .../foo2 and so on.  There wasn't supposed to any sorting, just separating:  "all paths that contain /special/ end up at the end of the array", _without_ re-sorting, because "[t]he original sort order ... must remain the same".  Given an input (a1, s2, s3, a4, a5, s6), the desired output is the un-sorted but de-interlaced (a1, a4, a5, s2, s3, s6) with the "special" s-es at the end.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example, you can simply use `asort($array);`

But that is assuming foo is always foo.

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "/something/foo1"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "/something/foo3"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "/something/foo5"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "/something/special/foo2"
  [3]=>
  string(23) "/something/special/foo4"
  [5]=>
  string(23) "/something/special/foo6"
}
```

If that's not the case, let me know and I'll do something else

... here is new method ref comment:

```
$array  = array(
    '/something/zoo',
    '/something/special/foo',
    '/something/loo',
    '/something/special/goo',
    '/something/boo',
    '/something/special/poo'
);
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $specialInA = strpos($a, '/special/') !== false;
    $specialInB = strpos($b, '/special/') !== false;
    if ($specialInA > $specialInB) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($specialInB > $specialInA) {
        return -1;
    }
    return $a > $b;
});
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [4]=>
  string(14) "/something/boo"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "/something/loo"
  [0]=>
  string(14) "/something/zoo"
  [1]=>
  string(22) "/something/special/foo"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "/something/special/goo"
  [5]=>
  string(22) "/something/special/poo"
}
```

Can probably be written better but should work

Comment: Oh, I probably should have mentioned that sooner. The actual paths are completely different. Just the `special` part stays the same. Thanks!

Comment: @rjdown, I'm not sure it's possible to write a sort comparison function that separates but preserves the original order of all the with-special and without-special paths, not without the array indexes also being passed in, or referencing the unsorted list in a closure.  Or wrapping each item and putting the index in the wrapper.  Sort will call the comparison with two elements picked essantially at random, and to correctly order two special or two non-special lines requires knowing their original index.

Comment: As you can see from the above, it certainly is possible. It's the difference between `usort` and `uasort` - _Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association_